# Is there a version of Latent Class Analysis with unspecified # of clusters

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, latent-class

I understand that you can use the elbow method to plot LCA solutions vs log likelihood to figure out, at which *k*, it is no longer worth it to add more clusters. And I will resort to this if need be. But I think it would be much more disciplined to infer the *k* from some Bayesian inference or maximum likelihood method.

I know that there are latent class clustering methods with unspecified *k*, such as the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (unspecified-*k* version of Latent Dirichlet Allocation). However, LCA is much closer to what I need than LDA or HDP.

Is there a technique that assumes no *k* and uses a similar model process to LCA to output the same parameters (mixture components, item probability matrix)? Or do I have to resort to methods that force me to run LCA multiple times for different *k* and compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dirichlet Process Mixture Models do this. With MCMC, for modest $n$ you get an item similarity matrix (O(n^2) so you will likely run out of space for this output before your inference algorithm stops working). You also get a particular clustering with each sample, and the distribution of $k$. The interpretation of the results is likely to be different than any finite $k$ methods, e.g. you're almost assured to get a mean $k$ which is non-integer.